# Missing some boosted trees operations in Tensorflow Lite

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite

I have a `Tensorflow` model based on `BoostedTreesClassifier` and I want to deploy it on a mobile with the help of `Tensorflow Lite`.

However, when I try to convert my model to the `Tensorflow Lite` model I get an error saying that there are unsupported operations (as of `Tensorflow v2.3.1`):

```
tf.BoostedTreesBucketize
tf.BoostedTreesEnsembleResourceHandleOp
tf.BoostedTreesPredict
tf.BoostedTreesQuantileStreamResourceGetBucketBoundaries
tf.BoostedTreesQuantileStreamResourceHandleOp
```

Adding `tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS` option helps a bit, but still some operations need a custom implementation:

```
tf.BoostedTreesEnsembleResourceHandleOp
tf.BoostedTreesPredict
tf.BoostedTreesQuantileStreamResourceGetBucketBoundaries
tf.BoostedTreesQuantileStreamResourceHandleOp
```

I've also tried `Tensorflow v2.4.0-rc3`, which reduces the set to the following one:

```
tf.BoostedTreesEnsembleResourceHandleOp
tf.BoostedTreesPredict
```

Conversion code is like the following:

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(model_path, signature_keys=['serving_default'])
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [
    tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS,
    tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS
]

tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

`signature_keys` is specified explicitly, because the model exported with `BoostedTreesClassifier#export_saved_model` has multiple signatures.

Is there a way to deploy this model on mobile other than writing custom implementation for non-supported ops?

Comment: Last chance for "free" solution - try converting with tf-nightly - most resent and sometimes buggy version. Fast search have not given any plan or status on BoostedTrees for tflite

Comment: Just for a reminder. Even if you manage to overcome this problem...adding the tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS means that you have to add this dependency inside android... This one line of code will add to your project 200MB because there is no option to select only the operators you want and you have to use all set!!!! I do not know if this a showcase or a production app, so take that in mind for your next steps.

Comment: custom AAR can be build with only required ops and drastically reduced size - [brew recipe](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select)

Comment: to a future reader: it seems it is not possible; XGBoost is a replacement, which can work on mobile.

Comment: @nikis can you please tell why it is not possible?